# How can I programmatically close the story editor in InDesign using ExtendScript?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I use a script which opens the story editor like this:

```
app.menuActions.itemByID(119793).invoke();
```

How can I close it programmatically? How can I detect whether it's opened or closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A story editor window may be closed with its [`close` method](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Window.html#close).

Here is a function which closes the story editor window if it's open. It tests for the presence of a zoom property on the window to determine whether the window is a story editor or not (Thanks Loic Aigon for this idea)... There must be a better way of doing this but I haven't found it.

```js
function closeStoryEditor() {
  var windows = app.activeDocument.windows,
    nbWindows = windows.length,
    i,
    closedWindow = false;
  for (i = 0; !closedWindow && i < nbWindows; i += 1) {
    if (!windows[i].hasOwnProperty("zoom")) {
      // Let us presume that a window without a zoom method is a story editor window...
      windows[i].close();
      closedWindow = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so this question isn't considered unanswered anymore

Answer (score 0):

To close it, it's…the same call ! if you want to check if the editor is already opened, you can loop through all open windows like this :
app.activeDocument.windows.everyItem().name;
and see for matches.

Loic
http://www.loicaigon.com

Comment: What test should I perform to determine whether the current window is the story editor window?

Comment: the story editor seems to have no zoom info while the main window has. I never used this stuff so I can't warranty it's safe but it's the only clue I can think of right now.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that calling `app.menuActions.itemByID(119793).invoke();` a second time does not close the story editor window after all..

Comment: I can, however, test if a story editor window is opened using the absence of a zoom property on that window. Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/kLbDU7pC

Comment: Nice one for the zoom property. For the menu invokation, it's weird. It worked here. What version do you use ?

Comment: Adobe InDesign CS6 (version 8.0) with ExtendScript Toolkit CS5 (3.5.0.52 ExtendScript 4.1.23 ScriptUI 5.1.37)